# Confused about function terminology

Tags: functions

Let $f: X \to Y$, $A \subseteq X$.

So, $f(A) \subseteq f(X) \subseteq Y$.

Then $f(A)$ is the **image of the set** $A$ and $f(X)$ is the **image/range of the function** $f$.

Is the above correct?

> Intersections are not always preserved **under the image of a function** unless the function is injective.
>
> $f(x)$ is the image of $x$ **under the function** $f$.

What's the difference between the bold parts in the quotes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above part looks good to me. You can also note that A is the pre-image of f(A).

I don't see a difference, unless it is a very slight one between the two bolded parts. The first statement talking about applying a function f to a set (specifically one that is the intersection of two other sets) and the latter is talking about applying the function to a specific element of X (presumably).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=\{1,2,3\},$ $A=\{1,2\},$ $B=\{2,3\},$ $Y=\mathbb{R},$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined by $f(1)=f(3)=0, f(2)=1.$

It is clear that $f(A)=\{f(1),f(2)\}=\{0,1\}\subset f(X).$ Indeed, in this example they are equal.

Now the statement is that the intersection is no preserved under the image function, that is $f(A\cap B)\neq f(A)\cap f(B).$ In our example

$$A\cap B=\{2\}\implies f(A\cap B)=\{1\}.$$ However $$f(A\cap B)=\{1\}\neq f(A)\cap f(B)=\{0,1\}\cap \{0,1\}=\{0,1\}$$

In fact, $$f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$$ holds, but equality is not always achieved. If the function is injective then you have equality, as the achievement states. Do you see the problem in this example? ($f(1)=f(3)=0,$ which makes $f$ not injective).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. For $f: X \to Y$ and $A \subset X$, we call

- $X$ the **domain** of $f$,
- $Y$ the **codomain** of $f$,
- $f(X)$ the **image** of $f$ (note: the image and codomain of $f$ may be different, *i.e.*, it may be that $f(X) \subsetneq Y$), and
- $f(A)$ the **image** of $A$ under $f$ (note: if $A = X$, the image of $A$ under $f$ is also just the image of $f$).

Notice that all of these definitions are only about *subsets* of $X$ and $Y$, *not* about *elements*. Since, given an *element* $x \in X$ it is also convenient to have a word for the *element* $f(x)$ in $Y$, it is also normal to refer to $f(x)$ as the **image** of $x$ under $f$. This is simply a different (albeit closely related) definition of the same word but for different objects (elements instead of sets). If distinguishing between these two definitions matters, you can usually infer what an author means from context (it's usually clear if someone's talking about a set or a point).

So to answer your second question, the first statement is using the first definition (for sets), while the second statement is using the second definition (for elements). The first says that if $f: X \to Y$ is not injective and $A, B \subset X$, it may be false that $f(A\cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$. In general, you only have that $f(A\cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B)$.

One small caution: Some authors will blur the line between these two definitions (and this is extremely common the farther you go in some branches of math); Since $f(\{x\}) = \{f(x)\}$ you'll sometimes see authors (incorrectly) refer to $f(\{x\})$ (*i.e.*, the image of the *set* $S = \{x\}$) as the image of $x$ when it makes a sentence flow nicely.